# DevExpress gridView - trigger javascript alert from onRowInserted event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a DevExpress gridView within an asp updatePanel.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upWWWGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdWWW" runat="server" KeyFieldName="WWWID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="false" OnRowInserting="grdWWW_RowInserting" OnRowInserted="grdWWW_RowInserted">   
                 <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0" Caption=" ">
                        <ClearFilterButton Visible="True" />
                        <NewButton Visible="true" />
                        <EditButton Visible="true" />
                        <DeleteButton Visible="true" />
                    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="WWWID" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="WWW ID">
                        <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>  
                    <SettingsEditing Mode="EditFormAndDisplayRow" EditFormColumnCount="2" />
                    <SettingsPager PageSize="20" AlwaysShowPager="true" />
                    <SettingsBehavior AllowSort="true" ConfirmDelete="true" />
                    <Settings ShowFilterRow="true" ShowTitlePanel="true" />
                </Columns>
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I would like to trigger a javascript alert in the onRowInserted() event by doing the 
following:

```
string Message = "Hello World!"; 
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "alert", String.Format("alert('{0}');", Message), true);
```

But it seems that the alert is never registered.  I believe the problem is related to the fact the the gridView performs everything using Callbacks.  Any idea how to trigger this alert after a new record is created?  Most examples I have come across demonstrate how to do this using a client side SelectionChanged event and onCustomCallback.

Comment: aren't the row inserts strictly server side?  Or is it close enough to have some event fired on successful callback?

Comment: I am able to run ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(...) during the server side event code, but because the gridview performs callbacks, the javascript is never triggered.  Technically I need a confirmation box, and based off the user's response I need to perform another action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```cs
protected void Grid_RowInsertedEvent(object sender, ASPxDataInsertedEventArgs e) 
{
    JSProperties["cp_RowInserted"] = true;
    ...
}

// I prefer this in grid's Init event handler but you can place it in 
// RowInserted as well
ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = 
    @"function(s,e)
    {
        if(s.cp_RowInserted!=null)
        {
            alert('row inserted');
            s.cp_RowInserted=null;
        }
    };";
```

Comment: I also asked this question on DevExpress' help site, and they responded with the same answer.  For future refrence here is a link to their answer: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q350078.aspx Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably register the onclick event for the grid on the row Data bound event. Here is the Snippet of code you may use it

```
protected void Grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{         
}
else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('I am here')");
```